# MS Search Server 2010 Express - SDK

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Is it possible to communicate with Search Service Application in Search Server 2010 Express via SDK?

I tried samples in Content API for FAST Server (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5210), but I was unable to send a request to the content distributor (even via SharePoint 2010 Management Shell).

I know this API is determined for FAST Server, so I want to know, if Search Server Express has possibility to communicate via SDK (Content API, or something else?).

Thank you.